# Jasmine fixtures for a Backbone.js view with attributes that are jQuery objects

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, fixtures, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to test a Backbone view that has attributes set to jQuery objects. I can test all the attributes in my view except the ones set to jQuery objects.

I've tried loading a fixture before instantiating the view, but none of the dom elements are found. I'm also able to use fixtures successfully when followed by assertions using jQuery directly. I'm just not able prepare the dom needed for the view to latch onto.

In the below example the spec fails and these are the values I end up with when I inspect via the console:

```
profileView.name  # => []
profileView.money # => []
```

What is the correct way to set up the dom for these kinds of tests? Is this the totally wrong approach? It's not the actual code but a fairly close example.

---

**Backbone View**

```
App.Views.ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend
  name: $('#name')
  money: $('#money')

  ...
```

---

**Profile Fixture**

```
#name name
#money money
```

---

**Jasmine Spec**

```
...

describe "ProfileView", ->
  it "money is present", ->
    loadFixtures("profile")
    profileView = new App.Views.ProfileView
    expect(profileView.money.length).toEqual(1)

...
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say `@name = $('#name')` in `initialize` or `@name = @$('#name')` in `render`? Assuming of course that your views aren't misbehaving by messing with things outside their own `@el` of course.

Comment: Yes, that approach is easier to test. I'm switching to that approach. Thanks, @muistooshort.

Answer (score 0):

As mu is too short mentioned in the comments, this isn't the right approach. Moving jQuery object assignment into initialize, render, or some other method is easier to test.